# ASP.NET Div with runat=server and InnerHtml html tag encoded anyway

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I have a problem with InnerHTML property of a HtmlGenericControl object. I thought that if I assign "<b>xx</b>" to a InnerText property it will get encoded - and it does - and if I assign the same string to InnerHtml it will not get encoded - but it does!! I am confused as it goes against what I have seen here in other posts.

Background:
The string that I am assigning is loaded from database and assigned to various other strings during its lifetime and then finally replaces a placeholder with Replace method. Still it contains "<b>xx</b>" rather than encoded version... To be absolutely sure I bypassed the entire process and assigned "<b>xx</b>" string directly in code behind - the result still remains the same (i.e. encoded).

Could someone please explain why this is happening? What is it that I am doing wrong? thanks.

**EDIT to make the issue 100% clear:**
I need to programatically assign "<b>xx</b>" into HTMLGenericControl object and have it rendered as HTML tags and not as encoded text. What happens is I can see "<b>xx</b>" written on the screen - not desired, I want to see bold text. I thought (and it is described in documentation as such) that if I assign to InnerHtml property that the string is not encoded and displayed "as-is". It however does not behave so.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the issue.  Is the problem that your string that is replacing the place holder is not encoded, but your placeholder has been encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is feasible in your situation to replace the HTMLGenericControl with a ASP:Literal control I would do that.

I just had a similar situation come up upgrading a CMS system and that was how I handled it.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggest and It worked. Thanks. Do you have any idea why it encodes HTML tags when working with property InnerHTML? It is written in the documentation that it does NOT encode html tags. I am confused :)

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure why. It seems like I just have to use that trick when I'm writing server controls. Maybe someone else will post up the reason. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
editable.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
stringDiv = sb.ToString();
```